# What should I use to get the title and post to show?

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask

I'm working on an assignment using python, flask-env, and my sql and I am stuck on trying to get the blog title and blog post to show. I can only get the name of the person to show(which I need but the other stuff is important as well).

If I leave the template with just "indiv_post" for both fields, it shows "None", but if I put anything other that or anything with it, nothing but the author name shows.

in my main.py:

```py
@app.route('/blog', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def blog():
    owner = User.query.filter_by(username=session['username']).first()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        blog_name = request.form('blog')
        new_blog = Blog(blog_name, owner)
        #post_title = request.form('blog_title')
        #post_entry = request.form('your_thoughts')
        db.session.add(new_blog)
        db.session.commit()
    post_id = request.args.get('id')
    indiv_post = Blog.query.get('post_id')
    user_id = request.args.get('owner_id')
    posts = Blog.query.filter_by(owner_id=user_id)
    blog = Blog.query.filter_by(owner_id=user_id)
    return render_template('indiv_post.html', owner_id=owner, blog=blog, post=post_id, indiv_post=indiv_post)
```

in my template(indiv_post.html):

```
<h1>My Posts</h1>

        <h2>{{posts}}</h2>
        <p>{{indiv_post}}</p>
        <p class="byline">Written by <a href="./blog?owner_id={{blog.owner_id}}">{{session['username']}}</a></p>
        <hr>
```

I expect the output to be show:
Blog Title
Blog post
written by: user

But I'm getting:
None
None
written by: user

Comment: it shouldn be variable `post_id` instead of string `"post_id"` in `Blog.query.get(post_id)`

Comment: When I leave off the quotations I get a "typeerror object of type 'nonetype' has no len()" error. This was my attempt to fix it.